# Web2py ajax function throwing index errors even when commented out or not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, comments, web2py, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to call the built-in web2py ajax() function using a possibly-empty array/list as a query string.  However, when the list is empty, ajax triggers a "list index out of range" error despite the fact that I check the list's length beforehand, and it even occurs when I comment the ajax call out.  Here is a simple example.

In the controller, `default.py`:

```
def commenttest():
    emptyList = []
    return dict(list=emptyList)

def ajaxtest():
    return ''
```

And in the view, `commenttest.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(parseInt({{=len(list)}}, 10));
    if ((parseInt({{=len(list)}}, 10)) > 0){
        console.log('List not empty');
        var firstListElement = list[0];
        //ajax('{{=URL('default', 'ajaxtest', vars={'actId':list[0]})}}', [], ':eval');
    } else {
        console.log('List empty');
    }
});
</script>
```

The problem lies in the line `//ajax('{{=URL('default', 'ajaxtest', vars={'actId':list[0]})}}', [], ':eval');`.  Note that it is commented out according to Javascript syntax.  When this line is removed, the program runs fine, and the console outputs `0` followed by `List empty`, indicating that the block of code containing the commented out text is never executed in the first place.

Is there any way I can work around this issue or prevent this error from triggering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a web2py view file, any code in between the `{{...}}` delimiters is interpreted as Python code and executed on the server before returning the HTML to the browser. The code in question, `vars={'actId':list[0]}`, is Python code, so if the Python list is empty, `list[0]` will generate an exception. It does not matter that the Javascript is commented out, as the Python code is executed on the server before the browser ever receives or executes the Javascript.

There appears to be another problem as well:

```
var firstListElement = list[0];
```

The above is Javascript code, but the `list` variable has not been defined in Javascript (it is a Python variable available only within any Python code in the view). So, that line should be:

```
var firstListElement = {{=list[0]}};
```

Or if the list contains strings:

```
var firstListElement = '{{=list[0]}}';
```

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that limitation. For what it's worth, that line was a mistake and not in the original code. Thanks for your help once again.